# Change the value of cell based on the value inputted

Tags: excel, vba, validation, excel-formula, vlookup

I'm trying to create a formula statement based on what the user enters into the cell.  If a user enters a `0`, `1` or `2`, the value of THE SAME cell needs to change. For example:

if a user enters "1" into cell E2, it needs to change to "2500"
if a user enters "0" into cell E2, it needs to stay at 0
if a user enters "2" into cell E2, it needs to change to "5000"

Is this possible to achieve?
If so, what formula is necessary?
I've tried different ways without luck, because I keep getting a circular loop error. Does that mean this is not possible?
Possibly with VBA?

Comment: You need VBA (scripting) to do something like that. A cell contains either plain data that isn't further processed, or a formula, not both at the same time, unless you have a script running to do any processing.

Comment: Thank you, I thought it would come down to that. Do you know how to achieve this with VBA?

Comment: I've had no luck on achieving this in any way, so I'm completely open on how to get this to work. Could you let me know how to achieve it with either of those options?

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
=VLOOKUP(A8,$C$1:$D$3,2,0)
```

in A9 will respond to the trigger value in blue based on a little lookup table as shown in the box.

With validation, in A1, Data, Data Validation, Data Validation..., Settings, Allow List, Source `0,2500,5000` OK. This will create the little drop down arrow which when clicked will open a little window from which only one of your three specified values may be chosen.

[image: SO21862981 example]

Answer (score 1):

You will have to attack this problem with some VBA; specifically a [Worksheet_Change](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx) event macro. Formulas cannot rewrite the cell that they are in if you over-type them with a value.

Right-click the worksheet's name tab and choose **View Code**. When the VBE opens, paste the following into the worksheet code pane titled something like *Book1 - Sheet1 (Code)*.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E2")) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo bm_Safe_Exit
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        With Range("E2")
            Select Case .Value2
                Case 0
                    'do nothing
                Case 1
                    .Value = 2500
                Case 2
                    .Value = 5000
                Case Else
                    'possibly clear the cell contents as undesirable
                    '.ClearContents
            End Select
        End With
    End If

bm_Safe_Exit:
        Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

I've left a commented code line to remove any entry that is not a *0, 1* or *2*. Uncomment it if that is the preferred behavior.

Tap <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to return to the worksheet. Typing any of the three values into E2 should have the desired results.

Note that [Application.EnableEvents property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821508.aspx) is temporarily turned off. This is because you are changing a value on the worksheet and want to avoid initiating another event that will attempt to have the routine walk on top of itself.